Traverse and mutate data based on GraphQL schema and query
I'm working with GraphQL on the client and I'm looking for a way to traverse and mutate data based on its declaration in the GraphQL schema and a specific query. My goal is to perform mutations on the data (e.g., converting strings to Date objects) dynamically based on the type information provided in the schema. Probably something like:
traverse(schema, query, data, {
    GraphQLScalar: (type, value) => {
        if (type.name === 'Date') {
            value = new Date(value)
        }
    }
})

I have implemented a function that works well for simple GraphQL queries (i.e., those without fragments). However, I'm encountering issues when dealing with more complex queries. Here's my current implementation:
import * as GraphQL from "graphql";
import graphqlSchema from "...";

type Jsonify<T> = T extends { toJSON(): infer U } ? U : T

const schema = GraphQL.buildSchema(graphqlSchema);

export function reviveGraphQLResponse<T extends object>(node: GraphQL.DocumentNode, value: Jsonify<T>): T {
  const newValue = structuredClone(value);

  for (const definition of node.definitions) {
    if (definition.kind !== GraphQL.Kind.OPERATION_DEFINITION) {
      continue;
    }

    reviveGraphQLSelectionSet({
      schema,
      value: newValue,
      selections: definition.selectionSet.selections,
      parent: schema.getType("Query") as GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType,
    });
  }

  return newValue;
}

function reviveGraphQLSelectionSet(params: {
  schema: GraphQL.GraphQLSchema;
  value: any;
  parent: GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType;
  selections: readonly GraphQL.SelectionNode[];
}) {
  if (Array.isArray(params.value)) {
    for (const item of params.value) {
      reviveGraphQLSelectionSet({
        schema: params.schema,
        value: item,
        parent: params.parent,
        selections: params.selections,
      });
    }
    return;
  }

  for (const selection of params.selections) {
    if (selection.kind !== GraphQL.Kind.FIELD) {
      continue;
    }

    const fieldName = selection.name.value;

    if (params.value === null || fieldName in params.value) {
      continue;
    }

    const parentFields = params.parent.getFields();
    const parentRawType = parentFields[fieldName].type;
    const parentTypeName = GraphQL.getNamedType(parentRawType).name;
    const parentType = schema.getType(parentTypeName) as GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType;

    if (selection.selectionSet) {
      reviveGraphQLSelectionSet({
        schema: params.schema,
        value: params.value[fieldName],
        parent: parentType,
        selections: selection.selectionSet.selections,
      });
      continue;
    }

    const field = parentFields[fieldName];
    const fieldTypeName = GraphQL.getNamedType(field.type).name;

    if (fieldTypeName === "Date") {
      params.value[fieldName] = new Date(params.value[fieldName]);
    }
  }

  return;
}

This implementation successfully handles simple queries but fails to address queries with fragments or more complex scenarios. I'm looking for guidance on how to enhance this function to support such scenarios. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

maybe you could use something like visit? https://graphql.org/graphql-js/language/#visit

@Sasha not exactly. it's only for the AST. I need to traverse through the data as well
